# Laravel filter nested collection

Tags: laravel, dictionary, collections, filter

I have a question that appears to be simple.

I will quickly explain the practical problem:

1. A **radio** has many **coordinates**.
2. I have a collection of **radios**.
3. I want to filter the **coordinates** based on a condition.
4. The below code doesn't work for some reason.

   ```
   $radios = $radios->map(function ($radio, $key) {

       $coordinates = $radio->coordinates;
       $coordinates = $coordinates->filter(function($coordinate, $key) {

           // return true or false;
       });

       $radio['coordinates'] = $coordinates;

       return $radio;
   });
   ```

I can filter the coordinates collection but can't "attach" the filtered array to the radio object.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT:

Try to change your function to this:

```
  $radios = $radios->map(function ($radio, $key) {

    $coordinates = $radio->coordinates;
    $coordinates = $coordinates->filter(function($coordinate, $key) {

        // return true or false;
    });

        $radio[$key] = $coordinates;

        return $radio;
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could u elaborate on that, please?

Comment: What does radio returns?

Comment: It should return a radio with a collection of coordinates, where some of the coordinates were filtered out. But when I return Response::json($radios->values()->all()); I get the unfiltered collection of coordinates.

Comment: but you don't filter anything..  in your filter function you should use for example,  `return $coordinate > 2;`  if you want only coordinates bigger than 2

Comment: $coordinate > 2; is the same as // return true or false; in my code right

Comment: I have return $coordinate->isTimedOut();

Comment: how you want to filter ? what condition you want to use?

Comment: But its not the filter function which is the problem. Its sticking the filtered collection of coordinates to the radio.